# The font-awesome icon does not show up on Chrome

Tags: font-awesome

I meet problem that fontawesome Icon does not show up on Chrome. ( Safari and Moz both works fine ). Does anyone have a clew why this happened. Thanks All.

Here is the Snapshot:

[image]

I know that the default font path that fontawesome.min.css directs ../font/......, but I have changed path name to " ../fonts/ " for my project, still doesn't work. The icon never shows up.

Comment: An easy way to debug would be to try using the CDN momentarily. If the icon appears, then you know you probably have an issue with the path to your local copy of the css file. CDN : <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 11):

Check if you have your Adblocker disabled. Sometimes chrome extensions can prevent the browser from showing the icons.

Comment: Any workaround this? I've disabled `Antisocial` filter list in AdBlock. It still doesn't work. Do I also have to disable `Fanboy's Annoyances`?

Answer (score 4):

Is bootstrap working? It looks like your Css directory is capitalized which would cause your reference to the css file to not work.

Try replacing

> ./**css**/font-awesome.min.css

with

> ./**Css**/font-awesome.min.css

As mentioned in the comment on your original question, you could try using the CDN momentarily to see if the icon appears. If the icon does appear using the CDN, you know you have an issue with your path like I have mentioned above.

**Here is the html code you would use for the CDN (version 3.2.1):**

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Aside from this, you are also using an outdated version of font-awesome. If possible in your circumstance, I recommend upgrading to the latest version. You can find more information on the latest version by visiting the following link.

http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

If you are going to use the latest version, make sure to look at [examples](http://fontawesome.io/icon/times/) as they have changed the way you write the html code.

**Edit after updating Font-awesome:**

If you are going to use the latest version of font-awesome, you need to change the HTML code to

```
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

**CDN for the latest version (4.7):**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Hi Kurt, bootstrap works fine. I just checked with other browser on safari and moz. this two works great. Just Chrome appears nothing.

Comment: Can you tell me what version of font-awesome you are using?

Comment: Kurt. I have updated to v4.7 and, still does not work in Chrome. Before my Fa version is 3.2.1

Comment: I updated my original answer. If you are going to use the latest version, did you change the html code?

Comment: Yep. <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>. I updated this code. otherwise Saf and Moz wouldn't show correct.

Comment: just chrome appear odd from the other's two.

Comment: That's really interesting. Can you try using the CDN momentarily and seeing if it fixes the chrome issue? Replace the href with https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: Love you man! That Works. How would this happened? It works absolute link path instead of local. Thank you very much. Great help. I could work more options on icons.

Comment: Well, I am glad that the CDN is at least working. If you need a local copy of font-awesome in your project, this leads me to believe that you may have some corrupt files or the paths to the icons in the css file are not matching where you have stored the icons in the font folder. That would require some additional debugging.

Comment: I see. it's not really a must use local file. that's because direct link load very slow here except connect a VPN. it's too much hassle. I have to switch connection all the time. anyway.  Thanks so much for the helping.

Comment: I tried on Chrome 63 Beta version and it works for me.

Comment: I have tried the, It is showing while decoding html page in my Asp.Net Project but now showing while printing (CTRL+P) the page. Also the test convert to different language...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and I resolved it with these steps:

1. Open your `font-awesome.min.css` file
2. Search for `webfonts`, which is the default parent folder name of the fonts. If you found a bunch, then replace each of them with the name of your `fonts` folder in your project.

**...This way, the font references inside your `..min.css`  points to the correct directory path where your fonts are :)**

I found out this out by opening `chrome dev tools` in `incognito` mode, and looking at the `console errors`.

Comment: Good one. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the plugin: "Font Changer with Google Web Fonts™"
I guess it comes as a default tool.

Answer (score 0):

There must be multiple css files.. You should include all.min.css (or) all.css as it works well

Answer (score 0):

Its because you need to provide the exact version of font awesome in the link tag of  index.html . 
For me it was:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" 
      integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" 
      crossorigin="anonymous">
```

you can also visit https://fontawesome.com/start and search for the exact version you need in your application

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem on one of my own sites. Only *some* of the icons didn't work. *fa-pencil* and *fa-trash*, specifically, failed. *fa-user-plus* and *fa-envelope* worked fine.

I'm not sure precisely what was messing with it, but one of the other css files (maybe bootstrap) was messing with the FA css. I moved my link to the FA css so it came after the other css links in the page, and it worked. I now have pencil and trash icons.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable adblocking plugins in chrome, they sometimes can mistake Fontawesome icons for advertising.

Answer (score 0):

Just add brand.js, solid.js, fontawesome.js file from your fontawesome folder, it did work for me.

```
<script defer src="../fontawesome/js/brands.js"></script>
<script defer src="../fontawesome/js/solid.js"></script>
<script defer src="../fontawesome/js/fontawesome.js"></script>
```